# AWS ECS Cluster: how to update a single docker if its task definition has many other containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, spring-cloud, amazon-ecs

I'm using AWS ECS to deploy Spring Cloud MSA by using 3 ec2 instances. 
2 instances is used to run spring-cloud services, like consul server, AP1, AP2, spring-gateway. 
Another one is an instance in small type which only runs consul server.

I have 2 task definitions:

One for deploying Consul which performs as service discovery and config server.

Another task definition is used to deploy dockers, like AP1, AP2, spring-gateway.

My question is that, in the second task definition, how can I ***only*** **update AP1** amoung multiple containers if a new docker image is created?

I tried to create a new revision of the second task definition, then update the service. But seems like all docker containers defined in the task difinition are updated, but not the single 1 which changed docker image.

Answer (score 1):

You [can not update one container](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/fargate-task-defs.html) if the are sharing the same task definition. better to place these containers in the separate task definition.

[image]

This because all container is part of single task definition, and each task definition run by service.

Comment: Thanks Adiii. I think service start up dependency can be controlled if I put them in a single task definition, and this is the reason I put them together. If they cannot be updated together, should I control the start up order by myself? Do you know if there is any strategy ECS have? (sorry for asking but I'm really new to ECS...)

Comment: you can check this link https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/03/amazon-ecs-introduces-enhanced-container-dependency-management/

Comment: Thanks for your info. I know if I define ap1 and ap2 in the same task definition, the start up order of these 2 services can be controlled via 'container dependency'. However, the side effect is ap1 and ap2 can not be updated independently. What I confused is that, if I seperate ap1 and ap2 to different task definitions, will tasks can have depencencies each other?

Comment: I think in different task definition I did not see such option where independent task definition can control the flow. because different task definition suppose to run on different instance while same container of same definition expected to run on same instance